# Variable elimination by clause distribution in Conjunctive normal form (CNF)

Tags: boolean-algebra

[I am refering to this document.](https://fmv.jku.at/papers/EenBiere-SAT05.pdf)

**The relevant part is:**
[image]

**My question:**

I understand that `(a or b) and (not(a) or c)` implies `b or c` but what really confuses me is the statement

"The produced resolvents $S{'} = S_x \circ S_{\overline{x}}$ ***replace*** the original clauses $S$ containing $x$ or $\overline{x}$, resulting in a satisfiability equivalent problem"

Given my example $S{'}=\{\{b,c\}\}$ would be satisfiable by $(a,b,c)=(1,1,0)$ but
$S=\{\{a,b\}, \{\overline{a},c\}\}$ clearly is not.

What what am I misunderstanding here?

p.s. Prefer ELI5 answer <)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both $S{'}=\{\{b,c\}\}$ and $S=\{\{a,b\}, \{\overline{a},c\}\}$ are satisfiable. That's all that matters.

The fact that $S{'}=\{\{b,c\}\}$ is satisfiable by some specific truth-assignment that does not satisfy $S=\{\{a,b\}, \{\overline{a},c\}\}$ does not change that: $S=\{\{a,b\}, \{\overline{a},c\}\}$ is still satisfiable, just by a different truth-assignment, e.g. $a=b=c=1$ will do nicely

Comment: Ok, that sounds like the root cause of my confusion. But then I don't understand what the point of this is, but whatever <3

Comment: @mangolassi By going through this process you are eliminating variables one by one. So at some point you reach an end point, and thus an answer.